# Solidity transaction error when transfer ether

Tags: solidity, truffle

env: mac, truffle, ganache

Is there anyone can tell me that why I can't transfer ether from one account to another? below is the test code and debug info.

```
truffle(develop)> web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[2])
{ [String: '80999999999999440773'] s: 1, e: 19, c: [ 809999, 99999999440773 ] }

truffle(develop)> web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[4])

{ [String: '98999999999999979000'] s: 1, e: 19, c: [ 989999, 99999999979000 ] }

truffle(develop)> web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: web3.eth.accounts[4], to: web3.eth.accounts[2], value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")})

'0xc56c7982006ed5bd9f47523c5f38e3e86185b389a02b7e7c4d23b1e33bd07224'

truffle(develop)> debug 0xc56c7982006ed5bd9f47523c5f38e3e86185b389a02b7e7c4d23b1e33bd07224

Gathering transaction data...

Addresses affected:
 0xc5fdf4076b8f3a5357c5e395ab970b5b54098fef(UNKNOWN)

Warning: The source code for one or more contracts could not be found.

Commands:
(enter) last command entered (step next)
(o) step over, (i) step into, (u) step out, (n) step next
(;) step instruction, (p) print instruction, (h) print this help, (q) quit
(b) toggle breakpoint, (c) continue until breakpoint
(+) add watch expression (`+:<expr>`), (-) remove watch expression (-:<expr>)
(?) list existing watch expressions
(v) print variables and values, (:) evaluate expression - see `v`


?:
(node:10530) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): TypeError: Cannot read property 'gasCost' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The debugger is used to step through a smart contract. You're just doing a simple ether transfer between two addresses. If you output the balances of your accounts after doing the transfer, you should see the transfer was successful.